# How to raise a ValueError?

Tags: python, string

I have this code which finds the largest index of a specific character in a string, however I would like it to raise a `ValueError` when the specified character does not occur in a string.

So something like this:

```
contains('bababa', 'k')
```

would result in a:

→ `ValueError: could not find k in bababa`

How can I do this?

Here's the current code for my function:

```
def contains(string,char):
  list = []

  for i in range(0,len(string)):
      if string[i] == char:
           list = list + [i]

  return list[-1]
```

Comment: Just like that, raise ValueError() hahaha

Comment: @user531225: Can you accept some another answer so that I can delete mine. Thanks :)

Comment: @THC4k: So weird that it returns the position of the rightmost occurrence instead of the count.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Obviously, he did—he posted to StackOverflow. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 190):

`raise ValueError('could not find %c in %s' % (ch,str))`

Comment: Did you know that, if you don't want to use the message, you can just `raise ValueError` instead of `raise ValueError()`?

Answer (score 29):

Here's a revised version of your code which still works plus it illustrates how to raise a `ValueError` the way you want. By-the-way, I think `find_last()`, `find_last_index()`, or something simlar would be a more descriptive name for this function. Adding to the possible confusion is the fact that Python already has a container object method named [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) that does something a little different, membership-testing-wise.

```
def contains(char_string, char):
    largest_index = -1
    for i, ch in enumerate(char_string):
        if ch == char:
            largest_index = i
    if largest_index > -1:  # any found?
        return largest_index  # return index of last one
    else:
        raise ValueError('could not find {!r} in {!r}'.format(char, char_string))

print(contains('mississippi', 's'))  # -> 6
print(contains('bababa', 'k'))  # ->
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "how-to-raise-a-valueerror.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(contains('bababa', 'k'))
  File "how-to-raise-a-valueerror.py", line 12, in contains
    raise ValueError('could not find {} in {}'.format(char, char_string))
ValueError: could not find 'k' in 'bababa'
```

**Update — A substantially simpler way**

Wow! Here's a much more concise version—essentially a one-liner—that is also likely faster because it reverses (via `[::-1]`) the string before doing a forward search through it for the *first* matching character and it does so using the fast built-in string `index()` method. With respect to your actual question, a nice little bonus convenience that comes with using `index()` is that it already raises a `ValueError` when the character substring isn't found, so nothing additional is required to make that happen.

Here it is along with a quick unit test:

```
def contains(char_string, char):
    #  Ending - 1 adjusts returned index to account for searching in reverse.
    return len(char_string) - char_string[::-1].index(char) - 1

print(contains('mississippi', 's'))  # -> 6
print(contains('bababa', 'k'))  # ->
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "better-way-to-raise-a-valueerror.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(contains('bababa', 'k'))
  File "better-way-to-raise-a-valueerror", line 6, in contains
    return len(char_string) - char_string[::-1].index(char) - 1
ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: "I want to use for loop :-)" was an early comment to the now-deleted answer by @pyfunc

Comment: @John Machin: Don't think I can be held accountable for not honoring requests in comments of deleted answers I didn't and can't see. However, even though my 2nd function doesn't use a `for` loop, it *does* in a way answer the actual question about how to `raise` a `ValueError` when the character isn't found in the string -- namely by calling something else that does it for you. There's also the prospect that the OP might get over their `for`-fixation or whatever it is after seeing a sans-`for` solution or becoming more familiar with Python later.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> def contains(string, char):
...     for i in xrange(len(string) - 1, -1, -1):
...         if string[i] == char:
...             return i
...     raise ValueError("could not find %r in %r" % (char, string))
...
>>> contains('bababa', 'k')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in contains
ValueError: could not find 'k' in 'bababa'
>>> contains('bababa', 'a')
5
>>> contains('bababa', 'b')
4
>>> contains('xbababa', 'x')
0
>>>
```

Comment: This function *always* raises a ValueError.  Not useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> response='bababa'
...  if "K" in response.text:
...     raise ValueError("Not found")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.