# try and except block for raising value error

Tags: python, try-except

I am working on a deduct amount function and it should raise a run time error if a < b in value:

here is my code

```
def deduct_amount(a, b):
    try:
        b - a < 0
    except ValueError:
        print(a + ' can not be less than' + b)
    else:
        c = a - b
        return c


deduct_amount(8, 12)
```

I know my try statement is faulty. how can I throw a value error if a is less than b

Comment: You don’t need a try block to raise an error. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4393268/217324

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

A `try/except` block is to catch an exception. You want to `raise` an exception:

```
if a > b:
   raise ValueError("a must be less than b")
```